# how can i write in a website and appear at another host instantaneously?

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web based text chat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396228/web-based-text-chat)

I want to create a webpage which allow me to share what i write in textbox and write it in the other host open the website ... anyone can help ?

thank you

amen

Comment: So basically a web-based chat system?

Comment: Oh, 'Amen' is your name, for a moment I thought final greetings and salutations had reached another level.

Answer (score 0):

store the 'writings' centrally (in some database)

then all hosts query from there.

Comment: i have this idea in my mind but im afraid about the delay , i need so rear time , do u have any idea about the delay?

Comment: the delay will depend on your database, which in general should be very tunable for this activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most basic method is by using ajax calls. One on every keyup to send the message the first host is typing. And one every second or so to get the message being typed.

Another method is by using web sockets

Comment: i haven't use ajax calls before , so kindly describe more how to do that

Comment: you can read more about it here: http://www.xul.fr/en-xml-ajax.html#request-step-by-step